# Scala's "for comprehension" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scala, underscore.js, lodash

I've gotten used to Scala's "for" construct and like it a lot.  I am now writing some JavaScript code and am using Lodash (basically an extension of Underscore).  Is there any way to mimic Scala's "for" comprehension in JavaScript?

My goal is to clean map/reduce code similar to this:

```
var rawCoordinates = _.map( directionsRoute.legs, function ( leg ) {
   return _.map( leg.steps, function ( step ) {
      return _.map( step.path, function ( latLng ) {
         return [ latLng.lng(), latLng.lat() ];
      } );
   } );
} );
var finalCoordinates = _.flatten( rawCoordinates, true );
```

In the code, I'm producing an array of coordinates in the format `[[coord1,coord2,coord3],[coord4,coord5]]`, where each coordinate is `[39.5, -106.2]` (it is an array of the coordinates of each Google Maps directions step).

In Scala, this same thing could be written like this:

```
val stepCoordinates:List[List[Tuple2[Number,Number]]] = for {
   leg <- legs;
   step <- leg.steps;
   path <- step.path;
   latLng <- path
} yield (latLng.lng(), latLng.lat())
```

Thanks!

Comment: In fact scala's comprehension [might be written like this](http://scalafiddle.net/console/46515dcd99ea50dd0671bc6840830404) so it will be even easier to comprehend

Comment: There is no need for the nested `for` in your Scala code.

Comment: Oh good point, I fixed that

Answer (score 2):

Javascript can't be extended with new keywords or operators, but those are not vital. We can live with usual functions, they may look not that nice, but pretty readable. Below is an example of a function that performs nested for loops.

```
function deepMap(xs, path, fn) {
    function impl(xs, path, args) {
        var result = new Array(xs.length);
        if (path.length == 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
                result[i] = fn.apply(null, args.concat([xs[i]]));
            }
            return result;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
                result[i] = impl(xs[i][path[0]], path.slice(1), args.concat(xs[i]));
            }
            return result.reduce(function(x, y) {return x.concat(y)}, []);
        }
    }
    return impl(xs, path, []);
}

// for generating lat and long functions
function x(x) {return function() {return x}}

// sample data
var legs = [{
    steps: [{
        path: [{lat: x(1), lng: x(2)}]
    }, {
        path: [{lat: x(2), lng: x(3)}]
    }]
}, {
    steps: [{
        path: [{lat: x(3), lng: x(4)}]
    }, {
        path: [{lat: x(4), lng: x(5)}]
    }]
}];

// prints [ '(1, 2)', '(2, 3)', '(3, 4)', '(4, 5)' ]
console.log(deepMap(legs, ['steps', 'path'], function(leg, step, ll) {
    return "(" + ll.lat() + ", " +  ll.lng() + ")";
}));
```

Comment: Implementation, usage, sample inputs and outputs. Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore and ES6 together support the following notation, which is relatively close to the Scala notation:

```js
var stepCoordinates = _.chain(directionsRoute.legs)
.map('steps').flatten()
.map('path')
.map(path =>
    _.map(path, latLng =>
        [latLng.lng(), latLng.lat()]
    )
).value();
```

Lodash supports this, too.